# How should I pass a SQL query to PHPgrid in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter as the framework for a commercial project.

The company deals with a lot of data and offers a lot of different reports. Up until now we have been using a datagrid to display the reports, and to generate the data for the grid the controller has been communicating with the model to retrieve the required data, and the controller has then been putting the query results into a local data array to be used in the grid as local data.

The way we want to do things now is to use a JSON data loading method, whereby the database query is passed directly to the grid library and the grid library will deal with fetching the necessary data in a class which is outside of the main CodeIgniter structure and will therefore run the statement outside of CodeIgniter.

**My question is:**

Up until now the query has been generated and executed in the model.
As we now need to pass the query to the grid library, the model is effectively rendered useless.

***But following the recommended structure for CodeIgniter based applications*** - should the query still be generated & returned by the model, or because the model isn't executing the query and communicating with the database, should the query just be generated in the controller & passed directly to the grid library to be executed?

Comment: @tereško I was just wondering for what reason you feel that the MVC tag wasn't required in this? as the question is mainly regarding the structure of MVC and whether the model should be used if it isn't actually executing the query.

Comment: Because codeigniter has **nothing** to do with MVC.

Comment: @tereško Firstly, CodeIgniter is based around the MVC structure. BUT that wasn't my question. My question isn't directed at CodeIgniter, so please re-read the question.

Comment: Model in [MVC](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) is a layer (along with presentation layer). Not a class or object. Which means that you question either makes no sense, or ir not about MVC.

Comment: When I refer to 'The model' I am referring to the relevant model layer depending on the report. As mentioned we have many reports which use many models. So I'm asking, in general, should the used function within model still be generating and returning the query even if it is not executing it (with the new method of generating data mentioned in the post). I can understand where the confusion has came from.

Comment: @Stanyer what you're referring to as 'the model' is more or less a domain object.. I feel you brother, I was also once a victim of false advertising.. but, codeigniter is not an MVC framework (yes, people mistakenly believe this) as teresko said.. just so you know. and no, you dont pass SQL queries, you should be doing all the query related stuff on the model layer, more specifically on a data mapper or an active record.. (this needs to be reviewed because i'm not as knowledgeable as teresko here..), now please review your knowledge on MVC and the CI docs is not, as they say, a good resource

Comment: @reikyoushin Thanks for your input! The way that I understood MVC was that you had three steps in the process, the controller works on the logic, and if/when data is required from the database, it calls a function in a model which returns the data after executing the query. The controller then takes the data, applies it to the logic where necessary and passes the output data to the view which then displays the data. So I was basically asking if, if the model won't be executing the query, should it still generate & pass back the actual statement itself. Much more confusing than I anticipated!

Comment: what you need to learn more about are [services](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html).. if you want to implement it in an MVC-ish way (true MVC can't be implemented in PHP btw). what you need to do is expose services to your presentation layer or whoever needs the data coming from the DB.. there are a lot of layers but you should be able to get it after some time hopefully..